# I downgrade my Eclipse cause I have to use that version in my class. Next, they occurs launch Error

Tags: java, eclipse, launch

When I try to build my .java source they don't work and give me this warn message. I try to find out the way to solve problem and change JRE build path already but it doesn't fixed... Could you help me please? I try to ask my professor but our school server is under inspection.. Sorry about my poor English, thanks to read this:D

[image: Error message from build]

My source code:

```
package ch01;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
}
```

I try to really simple code like this.

Comment: You will need to include your source code to be able to figure out what is causing the compile problem.

Comment: package ch01;

public class Hello {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello!");
 }
}

Comment: I try to really simple code like my comment right up this. But every source code include that encountered the warn message

Comment: You are using Java 17 with an eclipse version [that does not support it](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564922). Upgrade eclipse. Using old, unmaintained software can be a security risk.

Comment: I want to upgrade my Eclipse version but I have to use 12-2019 version for my class in univ. But when I try to run 2019 version eclipse gave me that warn message

Comment: Again, using old, unmaintained software can be a security risk. Upgrade. Or ask your school for support.

Comment: Uninstall Eclipse.  Uninstall Java.  Install Java 11.  Install Eclipse 2019-12.  Done.  Eclipse 2019-12 only supports Java 11 and lower.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc This is a pretty bad idea since there are no LTS versions of Eclipse. Simply use Eclipse 2022-03, which includes Java 17, but works also fine for projects using older Java versions.

Comment: @howlger If you can use older Java versions with the current Eclipse, surely Jean can do the same with the out of date Eclipse that the school insists on using. Can you provide a detailed set of instructions to make the little program above use Java 11?

Comment: @Sinc Eclipse supports the `--release` option which means all you have to do is to choose _JavaSE-11_ as _execution environment JRE_ when creating a new Java project. No need to install Java 11 or a different version on your system.

Comment: @howlger I think your answer to my question is the answer that Jean needs. Why don't you give that as an answer? The code is not the problem, it's the JRE version, so answer with how to set that, now that the project is already built, or to start over if changing the version on the fly isn't possible.